# Boolean Logic and Expression

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression

Simplify the expression below  using boolean algebra theorem.

A XOR B XOR A XOR ~ B

outline each step and indicate which law you're using in each step please.

Comment: Quit being lazy and do your own homework.

Answer (score 0):

Too simple, isn't it?

`A⊕B⊕A⊕~B  =>  A⊕A⊕B⊕~B  =>  (A⊕A)⊕(B⊕~B)`

- A⊕A=**0** (1⊕1=0, 0⊕0=0)
- B⊕~B=**1** (1⊕0=1, 0⊕1=1)
- 1⊕0=**1**

It refers to basics of this operation.

Comment: Can you tell me which laws you used and when

Comment: It was not `laws` as you mean. Its just a properties of this operation such as `commutative`, `associative`, etc. Have you ever seen truth table of this operation?

Comment: so which ones did you use for this particular question

Comment: and in what order because i see you have 2 dot jots

Comment: I've just updated. Commutative - to make order, associative - to split into two groups.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you were hoping for something like this...

```
A XOR B XOR A XOR ~ B
(A XOR (B XOR (A XOR (~B))))      Parenthesized
(A XOR ((A XOR (~B)) XOR B))      Commutative
((A XOR (A XOR (~B))) XOR B)      Associative
(((A XOR A) XOR (~B)) XOR B)      Associative
((0 XOR (~B)) XOR B)              A XOR A = 0 for all A; not sure of name
(~B XOR B)                        0 XOR A = A for all A; not sure of name
1                                 A XOR ~A = 1 for all A; not sure of name
```

Not sure what a few of those properties are named... the definition of XOR? These may be properties that are proven from simpler notions. In any event, they are neither commutativity nor associativity. Anyway, hope this helped.